# Why this 'itertools.product' does not run as expected?

Tags: python

I have two lists, a list of numbers `list_n` and a list of powers `list_p`. Then I combine these two lists in a list of tuples, `list_t`.

```
list_n = [2, 3, 5, 7]
list_p = [0, 1, 2, 3]
list_t = [[(n, p) for p in list_p] for n in list_n]
```

`list_t` is now:

```
list_t = [
    [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],
    [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)],
    [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)],
    [(7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3)]
]
```

So far so good...

In the next step, I try to create a combination list `list_c`, that looks like:

```
list_c = [
    [(2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 1), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 2), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 0), (3, 1), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 1), (3, 1), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 0), (3, 2), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 1), (3, 2), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 2), (3, 2), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    [(2, 3), (3, 2), (5, 0), (7, 0)],
    ...
    ...
]
```

But cannot get the expected list if I had tried the line below:

```
list_c = list(itertools.product(t for t in list_t))

# list c is now
# list_c = [
#     ([(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],)
#     ([(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)],)
#     ([(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)],)
#     ([(7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3)],)
# ]
```

Btw, I can get the expected list if I had tried with 4 distinct lists:

```
list_2 = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
list_3 = [(3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
list_5 = [(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
list_7 = [(7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3)]
list_c = list(itertools.product(list_2, list_3, list_5, list_7))
```

After the last line, list_c is now:

```
list_c = [
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 0)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 1)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 2)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 0), (7, 3)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 1), (7, 0)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 1), (7, 1)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 1), (7, 2)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 1), (7, 3)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 2), (7, 0)), 
    ((2, 0), (3, 0), (5, 2), (7, 1)),
    ...
    ...
]
```

Can somebody explain how to arrange the line below to get the expected result?

```
list_c = list(itertools.product(t for t in list_t))
```

Comment: To answer your question directly, that's just not how you do it. The question I linked explains how to do it. And just in case it's not obvious, the generator expression is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: ty @wjandrea, was so simple & worked like charm. After your comment, I remembered that I used trick several times when expanding an existing class & informing the superclass to be aware and `__init__` using `**kwargs`.